# How to do unauthenticated access using python-cloudant

Tags: python-cloudant

I am getting used to using [python-cloudant](https://github.com/cloudant/python-cloudant) for authenticated access to Cloudant databases but want to do unauthenticated access from a Python script.  I set up unauthenticated read access to one of the databases for my account and can read documents fine using `curl` without authentication but I don't know how to do this using python-cloudant.  I've tried using (`None`, `None`), (`"nobody"`, `"none"`), even some credentials that I use for databases for a completely different account but get denied access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got the right combination.  I don't know what I was doing earlier but when I authenticate with a valid API key & access token, I got access even though the API key doesn't have explicit access to the database.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `CouchDB` client and set admin party mode. That way you don't need to specify credentials in the client constructor.

```
    from cloudant.client import CouchDB
    client = CouchDB(None, None, url='https://user.cloudant.com', admin_party=True, connect=True)
    db = client['mydb']  # my world readable database

    print db.doc_count()
```

See the [docs](http://python-cloudant.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client.html?highlight=CouchDB#cloudant.client.CouchDB) for more info.